# Strange behaviour of StringBuilder and OutOfMemory Errors

Tags: java, garbage-collection, stringbuilder

i have task - need to get all combinations of elements in multi-dimensional, different size list`s.

When i put **sb** initialize in **(1)** place - i have Error: "*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*"

when i put it in **(2)** - it works faster and without errors.

And i can`t understand **why??**

```
public class Combine {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 140; i++) {
        list1.add(i);
    }
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 200; i < 350; i++) {
        list2.add(i);
    }

    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 300; i < 350; i++) {
        list3.add(i);
    }

    List<List> list = new ArrayList<List>();
    list.add(list1);
    list.add(list2);
    list.add(list3);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(doCombine(list).size());
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);

}

public static List<String> doCombine(List<List> list) {

    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.get(0).size(); i++) {
        resultList.add(String.valueOf(list.get(0).get(i)));
    }

    StringBuilder sb;
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (String tempItem : resultList) {
(1)         sb = new StringBuilder(tempItem);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
 (2)                   sb = new StringBuilder(tempItem);                     
tempList.add(String.valueOf(sb.append(":").append(list.get(i).get(j))));
                }
            }
            resultList = tempList;
            tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return resultList;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest that you reduce the number of combinations to generate (say, just have 2 elements in each of `list1`, `list2`, `list3`), and then print the contents of `doCombine(list)` - there is a substantial difference between the two approaches.

Comment: In place (1) you accumulate more data in `sb` so you need more heap.

Comment: thanks guys, now i see, sb append and append again in "j" cycle

Comment: Do you think `String.valueOf(sb.append(…))` is in any way better than a simple `sb.append(…).toString()`? Besides that, it’s a great example of how a simple `tempList.add(tempItem+":"+list.get(i).get(j));` would lead to the more efficient solution, preventing the errors you can make with your manual `StringBuilder` code…

Comment: @Holger, well, StringBuilder is faster, that's why he is there.  And S.valueOf is just for null pointer case.

Comment: There is no sense in protecting against an impossible null pointer case. The `StringBuilder` instance is never `null`. Besides that, the source code `tempItem+":"+list.get(i).get(j)` gets compiled to either `new StringBuilder(tempItem).append(":").append(list.get(i).get(j)).toString()` or `new StringBuilder().append(tempItem).append(":").append(list.get(i).get(j)).toString()`, depending on the compiler. As you can see, the result is equivalent or even identical to your faster variant, just simpler to write. You obviously never compared the speed but just claim “StringBuilder is faster”…

Comment: About  'just claim SB is faster'- look at code, i'm output run time. And if you replace StringBuilder by String, you will see the difference.